# How are UI event messages handled by the Main thread looper?

Tags: android, multithreading, events, user-interface, message-queue

Are UI events posted as standard Messages to the end of the Main thread message queue? Are they posted to the front of the queue using [sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue%28android.os.Message%29)? Or are they posted in any other way?

Please excuse me if this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

They're going to be posted to the end, or you'd end up with possible starvation situations where messages are never handled.

Answer (score 0):

Both Non-delayed messages (the ones posted using post(Runnable r)) and delayed messages (the ones posted using postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)) are appended to the end of the queue. However, you must understand that even the non-delayed messages have an implicit zero delay. In other words, each message in the queue has a 'delivery time' associated with it. This 'delivery time' decides the order in which the messages will be picked from the queue. So, for e.g. if your queue has currently a message with an explicit delay of 3000ms and you enqueue another message without any explicit delay, then this newly added message will leapfrog the first message to get executed first. And as far as sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue is concerned, you can use it exclusively based on your requirement in a careful fashion else it can easily starve the message queue, cause ordering problems, or have other unexpected side-effects.